# solve $\cos 2x - \sin x = 0$ using double angle formula

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve $\cos 2x - \sin x = 0$.

\begin{align}\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x 
&\iff 1 -2 \sin^2 x - \sin x = 0 \\
&\iff -2 \sin^2 x - \sin x + 1 = 0 \\
&\iff 2 \sin^2 x + \sin x - 1 = 0 \\
&\iff \sin x(2\sin x + 1) -1 =0\\
&\iff (2\sin x + 1)(\sin - 1) =0\\
&\iff \sin x = -\frac{1}2 \lor \sin x = 1
\end{align}

I could go on but the book gives the answer to this question $x = 30, 150$ and $270$ so I have obviously gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: This: $$ sin(x) ( 2sin(x) +1 ) -1 = ( 2sinx+1 )( sin(x)-1 ) $$

Comment: Let u=sin x and solve $2u^2+u-1=0$ via the quadratic formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fine up to here:

$$
2 \sin^2 x+\sin x-1 = 0
$$

You then write this as

$$
(\sin x)(2 \sin x+1)-1 = 0
$$

which is true (though not quite helpful), but then you somehow factor this as

$$
(2\sin x+1)(\sin x-1) = 0
$$

which is not right.  You should instead rewrite $2 \sin^2 x + \sin x - 1 = 0$ as

$$
(2 \sin x - 1)(\sin x + 1) = 0
$$

which will yield the answers in the book.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I do not understand is we have $(2\sin x = 1)$, sin is positive in quadrants 1 and 2 so we have 30 and 150 degrees.  But we also have $(\sin x = -1)$.  Sin is negative in quadrants 3 and 4 but the answer in the book only gives the value from the 4th quarter, i.e. 270 degrees.  Why is this?

Comment: Look at the unit circle: The sine is only equal to $-1$ at one point—at $270$ degrees, *between* the third and fourth quadrants.